# Selecting array to append to with ternary 'if' operator: "Immutable value... only has mutating members"

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var addedToIgnoreList: [String] = []
var removedFromIgnoreList: [String] = []
```

I want to append a value to one of these arrays. If I do it like this:

```
(isUserIgnored ? removedFromIgnoreList : addedToIgnoreList).append("username")
```

I get `Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating members named 'append'`

It works if I use intermediate variable:

```
var which = isUserIgnored ? removedFromIgnoreList : addedToIgnoreList
which.append("username")
```

Is using extra variable the only way?

---

**Update:** Extra variable will not work as well, so `if` statement is the only option. See accepted answer for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all related to arrays being value types, not reference types.  That is, the variables don't point to the arrays (unlike, say, an `NSArray`).  They *are* the arrays, and assigning an array to a new variable makes a fresh copy.

The reason you're getting that error is that this statement:

```
(isUserIgnored ? removedFromIgnoreList : addedToIgnoreList).append(etc)
```

makes a *temporary copy* of one of the two arrays, and the `append` call is being made on that copy.  And that copy will be immutable - this is a good thing, because if it weren't, you might unintentionally mutate it (as you're trying here) only to find that no changes occur - your copy is made, mutated, and then discarded.

Bear in mind that this:

```
var which = isUserIgnored ? removedFromIgnoreList : addedToIgnoreList
which.append("username")
```

*also* makes a copy.  So changing `which` won't change either original array.

The most straightforward way to change the arrays themselves is to use an `if` statement:

```
if isUserIgnored {
    removedFromIgnoreList.append("username")
}
else {
    addedToIgnoreList.append("username")
}
```

This will make no copies, and instead amend the arrays in-place.

If, on the other hand, you want a fresh array with the value appended, probably the easiest way is to use the `+` operator:

```
let newCopy =  (isUserIgnored ? removedFromIgnoreList : addedToIgnoreList) + ["username"]
```

Comment: "your copy is made, mutated, and then discarded". Well, that's definitely not what I expected. Thanks for your in-depth explanation.

Comment: "If... you want a fresh array with the value appended". I need to modify one of the original arrays and pass them both to a function, so this would not work for me. Thanks for suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1):

By doing that, assigning first the `which` variable, you won't be mutating the original array.

What you need to do is to append the element to the variable you want. I don't see any other solution than an `if` statement.

```
if isUserIgnored {
    removedFromIgnoreList.append("username")
}
else {
    addedToIgnoreList.append("username")
}
```